# Calling a subscripted regex pattern result after being used successfully returns 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, r, regex, dictionary

First of all I am very new to python. I started learning about a month ago so I know I am not likely using the most efficient coding techniques. However I am writing this from scratch and am trying to use code that I am familiar with.

The script I am writing is supposed to take input from a logfile and store the output in two dictionaries. One "error" dictionary which takes the ERROR lines from the log and stores the error reason as key and frequency of occurrence as value. The code accomplishes this task as written.

The second Dictionary takes the username as the key and then stores a two element list with the first element being the frequency that the user account is logged on an INFO log. The second element is the the frequency that the user account is logged in an ERROR log.

This is a segment of the dummy log I constructed for testing:

```
May 27 11:45:40 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO: Created ticket [#1234] (James.Mil)
Jun 1 11:06:48 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: Connection to DB failed (Matt)
May 27 11:45:40 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO: Created ticket [#1234] (Sean)
Jun 1 11:06:48 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR: Connection to DB failed (Matt)
```

This is my code so far:

```
    import re
    error = {}
    per_user = {}
    err_pattern = re.compile(r"ticky: ERROR: ([\w ]*) ")
    info_pattern = re.compile(r"ticky: INFO: ([\w ]*) ")
    per_user_pattern = re.compile(r"\((.*?)\)")
    with open(r"C:\Users\clher\OneDrive\Documents\syslog_test.txt", "r") as logfile:
        for line in logfile:    
            err_line = re.search(err_pattern, line)    
            info_line = re.search(info_pattern, line)
            user_line = re.search(per_user_pattern, line)
            user = user_line
            
            if "ERROR" in line:
                if user_line[1] not in per_user:
                    per_user[str(user_line[1])] = [0,1]
                elif user_line[1] in per_user:
                    per_user[str(user_line[1])][1] += 1   
                if err_line[1] not in error:
                    error[str(err_line[1])] = 1
                elif err_line[1] in error:
                    error[str(err_line[1])] += 1    
            #if "INFO" in line:
            #  if user_line[1] not in per_user:
            #     per_user[str(user_line)] = [1,0]
            #    elif user_line[1] in per_user:
            #        per_user[str(user_line[1])][0] += 1 
        print(error)
        print(per_user)
```

This code outputs:

```
{'Connection to DB failed': 4, 'Connection to burgers failed': 2, 'Connection to Ol DB failed': 2}{'Matt': [0, 5], 'Sean': [0, 1], 'James.Mil': [0, 2]}
```

Which is working great. However if I remove the hashtags from the INFO portion of the code I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-c676cd4cba24> in <module>
     22                 error[str(err_line[1])] += 1
     23         if "INFO" in line:
---> 24           if user_line[1] not in per_user:
     25              per_user[str(user_line)] = [1,0]
     26         #    elif user_line[1] in per_user:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Now this doesn't make sense to me as *user_line[1]* has been subscriptable up until this point and I cannot figure out why it would no longer be subscriptable in the "INFO" if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well after spending hours researching this error and subscriptable/non-subscriptable issues I just realized that my error is a simple white space issue. After correcting the indents on the "INFO" portion the code works as intended. Apparently actually posting my obvious mistake to the world was what was needed for me to recognize my obliviousness. Hopefully this helps somebody in the future.